# React Simple Side Menu not working with latest react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

simple sidebar not working with latest react-router-dom v5.1.2 but working fine with react-router-dom v4.3.1, screenshot attached.
[Github](https://github.com/HamzaMhadbi/simple-side-menu/issues/1)
[Working codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-dubinsky-v8827)

Error message

[image]

working screenshot with old router version

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Important**: This component must be used with React Router V4.

simple-side-menu package is not compatible with react-router-dom v5 yet.

Read more about it here https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-side-menu

You can also track this open issue here https://github.com/HamzaMhadbi/simple-side-menu/issues

Hope that helps!

Comment: that issue raised by me ;)

Comment: can i tweak the package? so it can run with latest router version.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution,open simple side menu package.json, then replace react-router-dom older version with latest one.that's it. :)